# jquery click add class and toggle div

Tags: jquery

When I click twice active class toggle keeps continue is there a way stop when clicked twice or is there a better approach?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnsbs .btn', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(".form").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnsbs">
  <button class="btn btn-buy active">Buy</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sell">Sell</button>
</div>

<div class="form" style="display:block;">
  form buy
</div>
<div class="form" style="display:none;">
  form sell
</div>
```

Comment: don't toggle, use `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: just like above toggle? $('.form').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple way to do that, just hide `form` class onclick, and show class mentioned in data attribute :

**Explanation:**

- `$('.form').hide();` will hide all form with class `form`
- `$('.' + $(this).attr('data') ).show();` will show form with class, you mentioned in `data` attribute of your button
- `$(this).attr('disabled',true).siblings().attr('disabled',false);` - prevents clicking of twice

**Example :**

```js
$('#btnsbs .btn').on('click', function(e) {

      $('.form').hide();

      $('.' + $(this).attr('data') ).show();

      $(this).attr('disabled',true).siblings().attr('disabled',false);

      console.log( $(this).attr('data') );
});
```

```css
.form {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnsbs">
  <button class="btn" data="form-buy" >Buy</button>
  <button class="btn" data="form-sell" >Sell</button>
</div>

<div class="form form-buy" >
  form buy
</div>
<div class="form form-sell" >
  form sell
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some if-else statements like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnsbs .btn', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  //Just check the button being clicked for the class you cara about using hasClass 
  if ($this.hasClass('btn-buy')){
    //Then set the text of your form element
    $(".form").text("Form Buy");
    console.log("SELL");
  }
  else if ($this.hasClass('btn-sell')){
   $(".form").text("Form Sell");
   console.log("BUY");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnsbs">
  <button class="btn btn-buy">Buy</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sell">Sell</button>
</div>

<div class="form" style="display:block;">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing utilizing the `disabled` attribute, this will disable the button and prevent user from clicking on the same button twice.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click', '#btnsbs .btn.active', function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');//remove default active class
      $(".form").toggle();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#btnsbs .btn', function(e) {
      $('.btn.active').removeAttr('disabled');//reset all disabled buttons
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');//disable button upon click
      $(".form").toggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnsbs">
  <button class="btn btn-buy active" disabled>Buy</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sell">Sell</button>
</div>

<div class="form" style="display:block;">
  form buy
</div>
<div class="form" style="display:none;">
  form sell
</div>
```